# How to make specific portion of lines in a plot thicker without changing colors?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I'm dealing with a dataframe of size (579x31), and I want to plot all columns except the `:date` column and modify the plot to change the line width of the last 30 data points in the plot.

```
using DataFrames
using Plots
using StatsPlots

# `selection` is a subset of a dataframe object.
p = @df selection plot(
  :date, cols(2:31),
  legend=:outerright,
  xlabel="Date",
  ylabel="Close",
  title="Stock Prices",
  size=(1000, 600),
  dpi=300,
  left_margin=5Plots.mm,
  bottom_margin=5Plots.mm,
  legend_title="DJI Stocks",
)
```

This gives me the following plot:
[image]

Now I modify the line width of the last 30 data points:

```
# Grab the default colors to prevent color changes in the modified plot
colors = [p.series_list[i].plotattributes[:linecolor] for i in eachindex(p.series_list)];

# Modify the plot
@df selection[end-30:end, :] plot!(
  :date, cols(2:31),
  linewidth=2,
  label=nothing,
  linecolors=colors
)
```

The problem is where it sets the color of each data point rather than each line (plot!):
[image]
(I used a magnifier to better see the problem)
How can I fix this?

The expected output is a plot similar to the first figure (`p`) with thicker lines in the last 30 data points.

## Minimal reproducible example:

```
using DataFrames
using Plots
using StatsPlots
using Dates

start_date = Date("2021-01-03")
end_date = start_date + Day(4)
df = DataFrame(
  date = start_date:Day(1):end_date,
  col1 = rand(5),
  col2 = rand(5),
  col3 = rand(5),
  col4 = rand(5)
)

p = @df df plot(
  :date, cols(2:5),
  legend=:outerright,
  xlabel="Date",
  ylabel="Close",
  title="Stock Prices",
  size=(1000, 600),
  dpi=300,
  left_margin=5Plots.mm,
  bottom_margin=5Plots.mm,
  legend_title="DJI Stocks",
)

colors = [p.series_list[i].plotattributes[:linecolor] for i in eachindex(p.series_list)];

@df df[end-2:end, :] plot!(
  :date, cols(2:5),
  linewidth=2,
  label=nothing,
  linecolors=colors
)
```

Gives the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tackle this problem by specifying a matrix of colors with the shape of 1xn (which *n* is the number of columns to be plotted) and pass it to the `linecolors` keyword argument to `plot` and `plot!` similarly:

```
# Suggest 30 colors
colors = permutedims(distinguishable_colors(30))
# Or specify them manually
# colors = [:red :blue :green :yellow :orange :purple :pink :brown :black :gray :lightblue :lightgreen :lightyellow :lightgray :lime :lightpink :Magenta :orchid :lightgray :darkblue :darkgreen :darkviolet :darkorange :gold :hotpink :midnightblue :yellowgreen :darkgray :steelblue :darkred]

@df selection plot(
  :date, cols(2:31),
  legend=:outerright,
  xlabel="Date",
  ylabel="Close",
  title="Stock Prices",
  size=(1000, 600),
  dpi=300,
  left_margin=5Plots.mm,
  bottom_margin=5Plots.mm,
  legend_title="DJI Stocks",
  linecolors=colors,
)

@df selection[end-30:end, :] plot!(
  :date, cols(2:31),
  linewidth=2,
  label=nothing,
  linecolors=colors
)
```

The outcome is:
[image]

Note that either `linecolors` or `linecolor` can be used interchangeably as of now in Plots v1.38.8 and GR backend v0.71.8.

Similarly, the minimal reproducible example can be written as following:

```
colors = permutedims(distinguishable_colors(4))

@df df plot(
  :date, cols(2:5),
  # same options as in the question
  linecolors=colors
)

@df df[end-2:end, :] plot!(
  :date, cols(2:5),
  # same options as in the question
  linecolors=colors
)
```

[image]